# Countdown letters solver - Recursive Python

Tags: python, recursion

```
def solver(word):
#trackerCount = len(word
convertedKey = sum(bytearray(word,'utf8'))
if(len(word)>=MIN_WORD_LENGTH):
    countdownLetters = wordmap.get(convertedKey)
    if(convertedKey in wordmap):
        for str in countdownLetters:
            if sorted(word)==sorted(str) and str not in result:
                result.update({str:len(str)})

    if(len(word)==9 and len(result)>0):
        return result
    tempList = list(word)
    for i in range(len(tempList)): 
        charTmp = tempList.pop()
        wordStr =''.join(tempList)
        tempList.insert(0,charTmp)
        solver(wordStr)
return result
```

I am writing a countdown letters solver using a recursive function. I want to completely STOP calling recursive 
function when i find the longest letters. For example, say I passed a word "education" to a solver function.
Let us assume, we don't have any anagrams of education, now I would like to check if there are any words of length (8).
If there are words of length 8, I want to return out of the function but if there are no 8 letters words I want to 
check of 7 and so on. Im only interested to find the longest words. Off course If I have more than one word of same (length)
as the longest word, I want to get them all. The above loop finds all the words from max length(9) to min length(5).

Explanation of the above code:
Basically, If I have no 9 letters(max) words then I am popping the last element, created a tempWord (wordStr) inserted charTemp(last element of the list), and called solver function with a letter removed. The above loop finds all the words from max length(9) to min length(4). 
The output of above code is here. http://postimg.org/image/pgfixbglv/ . please have a look, it might make more sense. In the image, you can see 9 letters words. I want my recursive function to return at that point, but if there are no 9 letters, I wanna look for 8, and again no 8 letters words found, move on to 7 and so on.At the moment to prevent StackOverflow exception I have specified the min word length. i.e 5.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in your termination clause;

```
if(len(word)==9 and len(result)>0):
    return result
```

This very explicitly says that you stop only when you've found a result from a 9-letter word.  Unless **len(word)** is 9, you drop to the recursion code.

As the old gag goes, if that's not what you want, then don't do that.  Just check that you have some result; if so, return it.  I can't tell if this, alone, is sufficient, since you haven't shown how you manage collecting all the results for the various runs through the lower loop (since you need them all), nor how you drop each of the 9 letters in turn, leaving the other 8.

Comment: I have updated the whole function. Would you please help me out. The problem is still there... if I type something like solver("edumation") instead of "education". Then it will bring the all 8,7,6,5.  If there are no 9 letters anagram of "edumation" . We check for 8 letters. Once we found 8 letters words, I want to exit the function but instead the above implementation brings all the words of 8,7,6,5 etc.

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but it's hard to do without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Unless we can reproduce the problem from your posting, we're "fighting with one foot in a bucket".  At the moment, I don't have enough info on what **wordmap** and **result** are.  Rather than speculate, I'll wait for the full example.  In case it helps, I have my own lexicon I can substitute for whatever word list you're using.